# Update if not exist

Tags: mysql

**Main_purchase** table with `(id,.....)` columns.

I also have **purchase_record** table with these columns`(id,purchase_price,sale_price,quantity,amount,remark,idstock,id_main_purchase)`.

And another table is **stock** table with `(id,item_name,purchase_price,sale_price,quantity,remark)` columns.
As foreign keys, `Main_purchase.id=purchase_record.id_main_purchase and stock.id=purchase_record.idstock`.

I want to update **stock** table's `purchase_price,sale_price,quantity` if item is not exist in **purchase_record** when I give item_name and **main_purchase_id**.

Comment: Please edit your question making it readable...

Comment: Please Edit Your Question and make it perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but you might try the following:

```
UPDATE stock
   SET purchase_price = ...,
       sale_price = ...,
       quantity = ....
 WHERE item_name = ....
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id
                   FROM   purchase_record
                   WHERE  id_main_purchase = ...
                     AND  idstock = stock.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to create an SQL procedure. You can achieve what you want either

- by using an `IF()` statement (`IF()` documentation for mysql http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx)
- or by using a `WHILE` statement. Example :

  `DECLARE variable [type_of_the_variable];

  SELECT [field] INTO variable FROM [table] WHERE [field] LIKE '%item_name%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
  WHILE variable <> NULL DO
   -- UPDATE instruction here and don't forget the semi-colon;
      SET variable = NULL;
  END WHILE;`

NB : as an advice, you should edit your post to make it easier to read. Use 2 line breaks instead of 1 and also put the SQL samples (even columns) as `code-like format` by selecting it and press ctrl+k or using the inbuilt editor.